# Why we need `afterEach(cleanup);`?

Tags: nrwl, nrwl-nx

This is question about unit test (jest + @testing-library/react)

Hi. I started using @nrwl/react these days.
This is amazing products and I'm excited monorepos project with nx.

Btw, there is `afterEach(cleanup);` in generated template test file.
This is my sample project.
https://github.com/tyankatsu0105/reproducibility-react-test-nx/blob/master/apps/client/src/app/app.spec.tsx#L7

However react-testing-library doesn't need cleanup when using jest.
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#cleanup

> Please note that this is done automatically if the testing framework you're using supports the afterEach global (like mocha, Jest, and Jasmine). If not, you will need to do manual cleanups after each test.

In fact, I see error when remove `afterEach(cleanup);` from test files.

> Found multiple elements with the text:

thanks!

Comment: OK. I understand. Now, `npx create-nx-workspace@latest` has dependencies `"@testing-library/react": "8.0.5",`. Automation cleanup function can use over v.9.0.0.
https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/releases/tag/v9.0.0